# Asking about a periodic function

Tags: calculus

Please help me to show that if the function $f(x)=\sin(x)+\cos(ax)$ is periodic then $a$ is a rational number. I don't know where to start. Thank you

Comment: period of $\sin x$ is $2 \pi$. Period of $\cos (ax)$ is $2\pi/a$. Try some values for $a$ and see when you can find a common period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that if $g(x), h(x)$ are periodic functions with period $G, H$ respectively, then the function $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ is periodic if and only if $G = q H$ for some rational number $q$.

This strips away the $\sin , \cos$ in your question, but might make more sense in terms of approaching.

Comment: Could we say that $f(T)=f(0)$? I amthinking of that.

Comment: @BabakSorouh You could, assuming that $T$ is the period. But you'd need more than that, namely you'd need $f(x+T) = f(x)\, \forall x$.